# Factoring a quantum state

Tags: algorithm, factorization, quantum-computing

I'm looking for algorithms that take an arbitrary quantum state made up of a sum of weighted classical states made up of bits, like this:

```
|0000>/2 - |0011>/2 + |0100>/2 - |0111>/2
```

and factor it into a more compact form using tensor products, like this:

```
|0> x (|0> + |1>) x (|00> - |11>) / 2
```

I want to use the algorithm as a way of visualizing/simplifying the state of a (simulated) quantum circuit.

For individual qubits I know I can just pair all the states with the state where the bit is flipped and check that every pair has the same x:y relation between the states. In the example above, flipping the second bit always gives you a state with a 1:1 weighting, so the second bit factors out as (1|0> + 1|1>).

But extending that approach to detect entangled bits (like the third and fourth in the example) causes it to take at least `Ω(n^c)` time (probably more, I haven't thought it all the way through), where `n` is the number of states and `c` is the number of entangled bits. Since `n` is already growing exponentially with the number of bits that's... not ideal.

Are there better algorithms? Representations easier to factor from/to? How useful is changing the basis? Links to papers would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267146/what-is-the-fastest-factorization-algorithm

Comment: This has nothing to do with integer factorization.

Comment: @Ashalynd That is an algorithm to factor integers into primes. What I want is more analogous to [polynomial factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials), though still different.

Comment: Should this algorithm be implemented using a [quantum programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_programming#Quantum_computing_language), or should it be implemented using a traditional programming language?

Comment: @AndersonGreen A normal programming language. I want to use it to visualize the state of a quantum computation, but since I don't have a quantum computer it would not be useful for the factoring algorithm itself to be quantum.

Comment: @Strilanc See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595156/software-simulation-of-a-quantum-computer

Comment: @AndersonGreen Thanks. I have already written a very basic simulator ( http://jsfiddle.net/xkCLq/24/embedded/result/ ), but before I work on the massive lack of optimizations I want to work on visualizing the state better.

Comment: Isn't the running time of your approach asymptotic to 4^b, where b is the number of qubits? The loop structure looks to me like, for each subset of qubits (2^b), for each setting of those qubits (2^c where c is the size of the subset), compute the conditional state of the other qubits (2^(b-c) coefficients) and compare.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Sounds about right. Like I said, `n^c`, which is `(2^b)^c`, was just a half-thought lower bound that was already bad and likely to be worse.

Comment: Ah, so `n` is the number of qubits, not the number of classical states.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, but the exact opposite.

Comment: @Craig: Can you give me a hint why "that is an algorithm to factor integers"?

Comment: @Craig: How did you finally solve the problem?

Comment: @HansStricker Since the full problem was NP-hard, I focused on "is a specific contiguous set of qubits indicated by the user separable from the rest?". [You can see it in action in Quirk's amplitude displays.](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22Y%5Et%22%2C%22X%5Et%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%5D%7D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an efficient algorithm is going to be hard:

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_state#Separability_criterion):

> The problem of deciding whether a state is separable in general is
> sometimes called the separability problem in quantum information
> theory. It is considered to be a difficult problem. It has been shown
> to be NP-hard.
>
> Gurvits, L., Classical deterministic complexity of Edmonds’ problem and quantum entanglement, in Proceedings of the 35th ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing, ACM Press, New York, 2003.
>
> Sevag Gharibian, Strong NP-Hardness of the Quantum Separability Problem, Quantum Information and Computation, Vol. 10, No. 3&4, pp. 343-360, 2010. arXiv:0810.4507